# ASP.NET MVC5 Como puedo crear un CRUD para la tabla AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio, entity-framework

Como puedo crear un CRUD para la tabla AspNetUsers, creando un controlador MVC 5 con vistas utilizando Entity Framework

Esta es la estructura de la tabla: AspNetUsers

[image]

Este es el Modelo: IdentityModels

```
namespace Portal.Models
{

    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public string Departamento { get; set; }

    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hola, bienvenido, podrías publicar la pregunta en español por favor?

Comment: @fredyfx gracias por tu comentario ya esta lista la traducción

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, es preferible en la medida de lo posible que deje código en texto y no una imagen del mismo, pues hace mas fácil su lectura para los usuarios, puede ver compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar, pudiendo acceder a editar presionado sobre el, y cambiando la imagen por el código. Saludos

Comment: @toledano gracias por tu sugerencia, hice la modificación

Comment: Hola, con "crear un CRUD para la tabla AspNetUsers" te refieres generar automáticamente el código de los controladores y las vistas con Visual studio, es decir, hacer scaffolding?

Comment: ¿Con que versiones de .NET, MVC, Entity Framework y Visual Studio estas trabajando? Quizas si aportas mas detalles a la pregunta consigues el voto que falta para que se reabra? :-)

Comment: @rsciriano es posible hacer scaffolding?

Comment: @rsciriano es .Net Framework 4.5, MVC 5, Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Answer (score 1):

Para trabajar con la entidad IdentityUser se utiliza la clase `UserManager`

[Introduction to ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

veras en el ejemplo como usa

```
UserManager.CreateAsync()
```

[Cutting Edge : A First Look at ASP.NET Identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605872.aspx)

En tu caso podrias usar esa misma `UserManager` para operar con al entidad `ApplicationUser` que estas extendiendo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un CRUD o Scaffolding de la entidad `ApplicationUser` de la misma forma que lo harías con cualquier otra entidad. Pero, **tienes que tener muchísimo cuidado** con lo que haces porque, como dice [Leandro Tuttini](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2600/leandro-tuttini) en su respuesta, **para trabajar con la entidad `IdentityUser` se utiliza la clase `UserManager`** (ambas de [Microsoft ASP.NET Identity 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/mt173608(v=vs.108).aspx))

El primer paso sería agregar el nuevo controlador con la opción de "Controlador de MVC 5 con vistas que usa Entity Framework"

[image: Scaffolding-Paso 1]

Después seleccionarías la entidad `ApplicationUser` y el `DbContext`

[image: Scaffolding-Paso 1]

Por último tendrías que hacer una par de modificaciones en el código que ha generado automáticamente

- En el `ApplicationDbContext` debes de eliminar la propiedad `ApplicationUsers` que ha añadido el proceso
- En `ApplicationUsersController` debes remplazar el uso de la propiedad `ApplicationUsers` por la `Users`

Como, decía al principio, **debes llegar mucho cuidado con lo que haces de esta manera** porque te podrías saltar ciertas cosas de las que se encarga el `UserManager` que te podrían dar problemas. **Yo te recomendaría que todas las operaciones de modificación las modificaras para hacerlas a través de él.**